# My SD card doesn't fit into my MacBook Air, but it fits into my MacBook Pro!

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, sd-card

My camera's SD Card can't fit into my MacBook Air's SD Card Slot. I can only push the SD Card into the slot halfway, but then ONE CORNER can't go in any further. The left corner of the card can still be pushed in, but the right corner is somehow blocked inside the slot. I'm pretty sure that's not how it's supposed to work, since SD Cards don't go in diagnally. Does my SD Card not meet Apple's size requirements?

Comment: sure the card reader isn't the other way up?

Comment: If I plug it in the other way up, the top-left corner of the card is blocked and the top-right corner can move in further.

Comment: sounds like something might be bent out of shape in there - torch & magnifying glass time, perhaps

Comment: @Tetsujin Being from the US I pictured you heating something to bend it with a flame torch rather than looking with a flashlight :)

Comment: @andrewmh20 - haha - sorry, yes, a transpondian translation I had forgotten about... UK torch = US flashlight. Well spotted... before any damage was done ;)

Comment: SD cards are all the same shape and size. Unless yours looks messed up. Either there's something stuck in your MacBook Air card slot, or you're not putting it in the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something wrong with the SD card slot

Comment: Wow! That's a revelation.

Comment: @Tetsujin `sure the card reader isn't the other way up?` Very close.

Comment: answers shouldn't be posted just to stop the Roomba but because they answer the question in a meaningful way. what is wrong with the slot? is there something in it? has something been broken in it? this answer is no way useful for anyone else who may have the same problem